Floating Marker (should be fixed location)
I've got a marker/map pin set at what's supposed to be lat 53.5788686 degrees, long -113.2774829 degrees. It's supposed to be at the Via Rail terminal in Edmonton, Alberta, Canada (a test case, no other significance). Well, it is -- at maximum zoom-in. Otherwise, it's significantly off the mark.
The further out the map is zoomed, the further south the marker wanders. At mid-zoom, the Edmonton train station is within the United States, and NO ONE would be happy about that.
It really ought to stay in one place.
testmap.js
import {Feature, Map, View} from './node_modules/ol/index.js';
import {OSM, Vector as VectorSource} from './node_modules/ol/source.js';
import Point from './node_modules/ol/geom/Point.js';
import * as olProj from './node_modules/ol/proj.js';
import Style from './node_modules/ol/style/Style.js';
import Icon from './node_modules/ol/style/Icon.js';
import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from './node_modules/ol/layer.js';

// object mapSetgs is global to this module, to better handle data changes

olProj.useGeographic();

console.log("map settings are zoom of " + mapSetgs.mapzoom + ", lat of " + mapSetgs.lat + ", and long of " + mapSetgs.lng);

const markers = new VectorSource({ features: [] });
// wps (waypoints) is global

function setMarkers(wps) {
    let i, x, y; 
    for (i = 1; i < wps.length; ++i) { // disregard inital center point
        x = wps[i][2]; y = wps[i][1];  // reverse lat,long to long,lat per OL practice
        const iconPosn = new Point([x, y]);
        const iconFeature = new Feature({geometry: iconPosn});
        markers.addFeature(iconFeature);
    }
}

let myMap = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    }),
    new VectorLayer({  
      source: markers,
      style: new Style({
          image: new Icon({
            anchor: [0, -0.5],
            src: './res/Google_Maps_pin.svg'
          })
       })
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [mapSetgs.lng, mapSetgs.lat],
    zoom: mapSetgs.mapzoom
  })
});

setMarkers(wps);

$("#map").show(); // in full app, map is normally hidden - not everyone is a map user

// EOF

testmap.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test Open Layers Map</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://openlayers.org/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="res/mapstyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="res/DMTP_v24A3.css">

    <script src="res/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
const wps = [ /* point id, lat, long, descr */
    [ 69, 47.40671668, -113.2774829, "map ctr"],
    [283, 53.5788686,  -113.5307153, "Edmonton train sta"]
], mapSetgs = {mapzoom: 5, lat: wps[0][1], lng: wps[0][2] };
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Test Open Layers Map</h3>
<div id='map' style='width:80%; height:80%;'></div>
<script type="module" src="./testmap.js"></script>
</body>
</html> 


You have the wrong anchor for that icon, should be [0.5, 1.0]
new ol.layer.Vector ({// VectorLayer({  
  source: markers,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Icon({
        anchor: [0.5, 1.0],
        src: 'http://www.geocodezip.com/mapIcons/Google_Maps_pin.svg' 
      })
  })
}),

proof of concept

code snippet


const wps = [ /* point id, lat, long, descr */
    [ 69, 47.40671668, -113.2774829, "map ctr"],
    [283, 53.5788686,  -113.5307153, "Edmonton train sta"]
], mapSetgs = {mapzoom: 15, lat: wps[0][1], lng: wps[0][2] };
ol.proj.useGeographic();

console.log("map settings are zoom of " + mapSetgs.mapzoom + ", lat of " + mapSetgs.lat + ", and long of " + mapSetgs.lng);

const markers = new ol.source.Vector({ features: [] }); // VectorSource({ features: [] });
// wps (waypoints) is global

function setMarkers(wps) {
    let i, x, y; 
    for (i = 1; i < wps.length; ++i) { // disregard inital center point
        x = wps[i][2]; y = wps[i][1];  // reverse lat,long to long,lat per OL practice
        const iconPosn = new ol.geom.Point([x, y]);
        const iconFeature = new ol.Feature({geometry: iconPosn});
        markers.addFeature(iconFeature);
    }
}
var svg = '<svg width="120" height="120" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">'
    + '<circle cx="60" cy="60" r="60" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" fill="white" />'
    + '</svg>';
let myMap = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({ // TileLayer({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    new ol.layer.Vector ({// VectorLayer({  
      source: markers,
      style: new ol.style.Style({
          image: new ol.style.Icon({
            anchor: [0.5, 1.0],
            src: 'https://www.geocodezip.net/mapIcons/Google_Maps_pin.svg' 
          })
       })
    }),
    new ol.layer.Vector ({// VectorLayer({  
      source: markers,
      style: new ol.style.Style({
         image: new ol.style.Icon({
           opacity: 1,
           src: 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,' + encodeURI(svg),
           scale: 0.05,
           color: "#ff4646"
         })
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-113.5307153,53.5788686],
    zoom: mapSetgs.mapzoom
  })
});

setMarkers(wps);

$("#map").show(); // in full app, map is normally hidden - not everyone is a map user
html, body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
  }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test Open Layers Map</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://openlayers.org/favicon.ico" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v10.3.1/dist/ol.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v10.3.1/ol.css">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Test Open Layers Map</h3>
<div id='map' style='width:80%; height:80%;'></div>
</body>
</html>



